# A returned Promise with Fetch doesn't respond to .then()

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I'm a bit confused here, this part of some async code isn't working. Here's the problem:

```js
export async function active() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
        fetch("https://api.spotify.com/v1/me", { //omitted headers to keep it clean
        }).then(response => console.log(response)) <-- This code runs, and will log a response
        .then(data => function(){ <-- but this won't
            console.log("This won't run either")
            if (data.status == 200) {
                console.log(true)
                resolve(data)
            } else {
                console.log(false)
                reject(data)
            }
        })
    })
}
```

Why isn't the second part running? Sorry, I'm a bit new to async/await

Comment: what is `.this`? what is `data`? in the second .then? hint: it's the result of `console.log` which is `undefined`

Comment: `data => function(){` you realise this returns a function which is never run?

Comment: Why are you using the promise constructor anti-pattern and .then when you also already have promises and are in an async function?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a few problems there

1. `.then(data => function(){` passes a function that returns a function into `.then`. You want *either* an arrow function *or* the `function` keyword but not both. Since all you're doing is returning a function (which nothing calls), you don't see the contents of that function run. Get rid of the `function()` part of that.
2. There's no reason for `new Promise` in that code (and no reason for your function to be `async`), just use the promise chain you have from `fetch`. (More [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-explicit-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it).)
3. Your first `then` handler returns `undefined`, because you're returning the result of `console.log`.
4. Your code uses the name `data` where you're still dealing with a [Response](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response) object whose body you haven't yet read. You probably want to read the body, via the `.text()`, `.json()`, or other similar body-reading methods.

Instead:

```
export function active() {
    return fetch("https://api.spotify.com/v1/me", { //omitted headers to keep it clean
    })
    .then(response => {
        if (!repsonse.ok) {
            throw new Error("HTTP status " + response.status);
        }
        return response.text(); // or `.json()` or several others, see #4 above
    });
}
```

Note I changed the check for success there slightly.

Comment: also `data` will be `undefined` since `console.log` returns `undefined`

Comment: @Bravo - Yeah, and a couple of other things. :-)

Comment: Yeah, like the promise constructor anti-pattern

Comment: yeah, didn't even notice the superfluous `async`